# How can I pass a reference in the TemplateParameterObject parameter when deploying an ARMtemplate

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-rm-template

When executing the `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment` command you can pass template parameters via the `TemplateParameterObject` parameter.  That works great for simple properties and arrays but I cannot seem to get it to work for references.  So something that would look like this in an ARM template parameter file:

```
"adminPassword": {
  "reference": {
    "keyVault": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/365d8c14-efa0-437e-a2c8-c3ffc8f6287a/resourceGroups/musw1-prf-jboyd-kv-rg/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/musw1-prf-jboyd-kv"
    },
    "secretName": "adminPassword"
  }
}
```

I have tried this:

```
$parameters = @{
    adminPassword = @{
        reference = @{
            keyVault = @{
                id = $KeyVaultId
            }
            secretName = 'adminPassword'
        }
    }
}

New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment `
    -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
    -TemplateFile $TemplateFile `
    -TemplateParameterObject $parameters
```

But all I get is:

> Deployment template validation failed: 'The provided value for the template parameter 'adminPassword' at line '13' and column '27' is not valid.'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Key Vault references in ARM Template Parameters appears only to be supported via Parameter Files and not Parameter Objects: [See here for the issue that's been raised with Microsoft](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/2336)

Whilst it's not as friendly as using `-TemplateParameterObject`, one work-around which would allow you scripting without exposing your Key Vault secrets, would be to programatically create and populate your JSON Template file via PowerShell, then pass that into `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`.  By doing this, you can continue to reference the Key Vault secret indirectly without storing it locally or exposing it as clear text in any way.

Comment: Actually, this is what I ended up doing.

Comment: I'll give you the points now but you have to come back and update your answer when they add support for it :)

Comment: Ha ha - it's a deal ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround without using the `TemplateParameterObject` parameter in PowerShell is by adding a nested template and pass in a parameter that contains a [reference to the dynamically generated Azure Key Vault resource ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter?tabs=azure-powershell#reference-secrets-with-dynamic-id).